# Cannot run roscore, rosmake with python 3

Tags: roscore

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,

I got SyntaxError when run roscore, rosmake, rosversion ...

```
tienthanh@tienthanh-pc:~$ roscore
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/roscore", line 34, in <module>
    from ros import roslaunch
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/core/roslib/src/ros/__init__.py", line 55
    except roslib.packages.InvalidROSPkgException, e:
                                                 ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

tienthanh@tienthanh-pc:~$ roscd rgbdslam && rosmake --rosdep-install rgbdslam
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/rosmake", line 46
    print "Rospack failed to build" 
                                  ^
tienthanh@tienthanh-pc:/opt/ros/diamondback/stacks/rgbdslam$ rosversion
  File "/opt/ros/diamondback/ros/bin/rosversion", line 55
    except Exception, e:
                    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9791/cannot-run-roscore,-rosmake-with-python-3/) by [Tien Thanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/135/tien-thanh/) on ROS Answers with karma: 231 on 2011-04-20

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tien Thanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/135/tien-thanh/) on 2011-04-21**:
python --version
Python 3.1.2

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-04-20**:
Which version of python are you running?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For python 3 support, you should have a look at this ticket:
https://code.ros.org/trac/ros/ticket/3166

But I think you're going to have some trouble getting ROS to work on python 3. Can't you use python2 instead? Or are you running Arch Linux?

Cheers,

Ugo

---

Originally posted by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) with karma: 1620 on 2011-04-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Tien Thanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/135/tien-thanh/) on 2011-04-21**:
I change the link in python in robotpkg to /usr/bin/python2.6 and it works. But I'm not sure package in robotpkg still work probaly. Thank you anyways.

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-04-21**:
Then you should probably have a look at your PATH and see where python 3 is installed (may be /usr/local/bin?). If you do export PATH=/usr/bin and check python --version it should give you python 2.6.

**Comment by [Tien Thanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/135/tien-thanh/) on 2011-04-21**:
Yes the ln -s /usr/bin/python is linked to /usr/bin/python2.6. I installed python3 through robotpkg http://softs.laas.fr/openrobots/robotpkg/README.html#tth_sEc2.1.3.

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-04-21**:
and ls -l /usr/bin/python is linked to /usr/bin/python2.6? How did you install python3? Through apt-get?

**Comment by [Tien Thanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/135/tien-thanh/) on 2011-04-21**:
Python 3.1.2

**Comment by [Ugo](https://answers.ros.org/users/72/ugo/) on 2011-04-21**:
You ran update-alternatives and selected python 2.6? What does python --version return?

**Comment by [Tien Thanh](https://answers.ros.org/users/135/tien-thanh/) on 2011-04-21**:
I use Ubuntu 10.04, I tried to change the python default version to 2.6 with sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python-config2.6 /usr/bin/python-config and sudo ln -s /usr/bin/python2.6 /usr/bin/python. But it's not work. I also tried with update-alternatives, but that no help. How to change back to python2.6?